# Evitar Overloading de atributos quando usado métodos magicos

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte classe PHP:

```
<?php
class User{
    private $email = null;
    private $pass = null;

    public function __set($atrib, $value){
        $this->$atrib = $value;
    }

     public function __get($atrib){
        return $this->$atrib;
    }
}
?>
```

quando estava testando obtive o seguinte erro:`INDIRECT MODIFICATION OF OVERLOADED PROPERTY HAS NO EFFECT` pesquisei e vi que este erro está diretamente ligado aos metodos mágicos então busquei uma solução para o problema, removi os atributos $email e $pass da classe o problema foi resolvido mas isso lenvantou uma questão: Como eu poderia determinar os atributos da classe sem gerar o erro: `Inderect modification ...`?

Exemplo de uso:

```
$user = new User();
$user->email = $_GET['email'];
$user->pass = $_GET['pass'];
loginSearch($conn,$user);
function loginSearch($conn,$user){
        $query = "SELECT email, pass FROM usuarios WHERE email = :email AND pass = :pass";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(':email',$user->email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':pass',$user->pass,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        return $stmt;
    }
```

O Erro acontece nas linhas: `$stmt->bindParam(':email',$user->email,PDO::PARAM_STR);` e `$stmt->bindParam(':pass',$user->pass,PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Obs: Omite a criação da conexão e o `execute` do stmt.

Imagem do erro gerado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você tem certeza que este é o código que está usando. Vi um erro nele e não está relacionado com o que você estava dizendo. O que você está dizendo que acontece eu não consegui reproduzir. Fiz testes diferentes e sempre funciona http://ideone.com/YzRCJz Uma coisa você não respondeu, para que ocê está usando os métodos mágicos? Eles parecem estar sem função. Na verdade raramente eles são úteis se quiser manter o código organizado.

Comment: Qual versão do php está usando?

Comment: @bigown, aqui tem um código que simula o erro: https://phpolyk.wordpress.com/2012/07/25/indirect-modification-of-overloaded-property/

Comment: @bigown Estou usando para poder setar e recuperar os valores sem ter de acessar metodos ex: $nome = $usuario->nome;

Comment: Mas isto não é o que você está fazendo, não adianta pegar erros que outro códigos estão gerando. Tem que fazer em cima do seu. Se você está fazendo diferente do que você está postando fica complicado. Eu mexi mais no exemplo e continua funcionando sem problemas.

Comment: @bigown, este erro esta acontecendo com o meu código, este postado na pergunta esta sendo impresso um notice na tela com o erro, irei adicionar um print

Comment: É, mas tem algumas pessoas tentando reproduzir e ninguém consegue fazer ele acontecer, então tem alguma outra coisa que está faltando. Se você não conseguir informações consistentes acho que ninguém vai conseguir te ajudar.

Comment: @bigown o meu intuito de uso dos métodos __set e __get é não necessitar o uso de chamadas de função para setar e recuperar valores das variáveis, usaria a variável como se ela fosse publica, da forma como estou usando funciona porem é exibido um notice com o erro.

Comment: @bigown levando em conta o notice creio que o __set esta criando uma outra variavel com o mesmo da ja criado dentro da classe ($email,$pass)

Comment: Notice não é erro, é aviso que você está fazendo algo não recomendado. Mesmo assim não acontece comigo você pode ver. Eu usei, na medida do possível, o mesmo código que você. De qualquer forma se ainda quer que eu veja ele ocorrendo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @bigown os codigos estão em arquivos diferentes, logo ficar passando os objetos de um arquivo pro ouro

Comment: Parece ser um bug do PHP.
Veja esses links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452519/php-notice-when-binding-overloaded-property-in-pdostatementbindparam

Comment: no google encontrei esses outro: http://www.1x1.jp/blog/2006/11/php___get_array.html

Comment: Ao que parece no link postado pelo @DanielOmine há a resposta para seu problema, segundo a explicação `PDO::bindParam` deve receber uma referência para uma variável, mas você está passando o retorno da função `User::__get` que não pode ser transformado em referência, por isso do erro.

Comment: @Cahe é gerado um `notice` porem é executado o statment

Comment: Sim, com 'erro' eu quis dizer 'notice', de qualquer maneira o link postado pelo Daniel contém a explicação para seu problema.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando tive esse problema, a solução foi declarar `__get` com retorno por referência.

Isso pode ser feito através do caractere `&`.

Veja:

```
<?php
class User{
    private $email = null;
    private $pass = null;

    public function __set($atrib, $value){
        $this->$atrib = $value;
    }

     public function &__get($atrib){
        return $this->$atrib;
    }
}
?>
```